# Ansible Jinja2, formatting

Tags: ansible, jinja2

so currently I run a for loop to produce a list of addresses, here is the loop:

```
sg_nodes_dn: "
  {%- set nodes = [] %}
  {%- for host in groups['elastic_nodes'] %}
  {{- nodes.append('CN=%s,OU=Systems/DevOps,O=x x x,L=x,C=x' % hostvars[host]['elk_node_name']) }}
  {%- endfor %}
  {{- nodes -}}"
```

This works great, however the problem I have is when I format it into a j2 template.

Here is the var inside my template:

```
searchguard.nodes_dn:
    {{ sg_nodes_dn | to_nice_yaml }}
```

The problem with this is, it will print the first line fine, however the second line is not formatted in yaml and the service will fail to load, the outcome of this is.

```
searchguard.nodes_dn:
    - CN=x.x-x.x,OU=Systems/DevOps,O=x x x,L=x,C=x
- CN=x.x-x.x,OU=Systems/DevOps,O=x x x,L=x,C=x
```

How can I ensure that the second line is properly formatted? I did some brief reading and added:

```
#jinja2:trim_blocks: False
```

To the top of the file, but it didn't resolve the issue, can anyone other any input here?

Comment: Can you try `#jinja2: lstrip_blocks: "True (or False)", trim_blocks: "True (or False)"` toggle fasle and true to check weather you can get you desired result.

Comment: Unfortunately not, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Jinja2 [`indent`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#indent) filter :

```
searchguard.nodes_dn:
    {{ sg_nodes_dn | to_nice_yaml | indent(4, false) }}
```

Or simply use default parameters (`width=4` and `indentfirst=False`), which are exactly what you need:

```
searchguard.nodes_dn:
    {{ sg_nodes_dn | to_nice_yaml | indent }}
```

Comment: Note that indent is a Jinja2 filter, whereas to_nice_yaml is an Ansible plugin.